# python - Directly Send Files to S3 From Django on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3

So I'm trying to uploaded larger files to my site, and due to Herokus limitations with the sizes, I'm trying to upload them directly to S3. Heroku provides great documentation on how to do so, [seen here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python). I'm following along with the guide, and adjusting my `views.py` based on [this Git](https://gist.github.com/RyanBalfanz/f07d827a4818fda0db81). The problem is my signing request doesn't work when trying to post to S3. I get the error

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

So i am unsure of how my signature is wrong or if there is something wrong in my javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

My views.py

```
def sign_s3(request):
    """
    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python
    """

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user.id

    AWS_ACCESS_KEY = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    AWS_SECRET_KEY = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    S3_BUCKET = AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

    object_name = urllib.parse.quote_plus(request.GET['file_name'])

    mime_type = request.GET['file_type']

    secondsPerDay = 24*60*60
    expires = int(time.time()+secondsPerDay)
    amz_headers = "x-amz-acl:public-read"

    string_to_sign = "PUT\n\n%s\n%d\n%s\n/%s/%s" % (mime_type, expires, amz_headers, S3_BUCKET, object_name)

    encodedSecretKey = AWS_SECRET_KEY.encode()
    encodedString = string_to_sign.encode()
    h = hmac.new(encodedSecretKey, encodedString, sha1)
    hDigest = h.digest()
    signature = base64.encodebytes(hDigest).strip()
    print(signature)
    signature = urllib.parse.quote_plus(signature)
    print(signature)
    url = 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/user_%s/%s/' % (S3_BUCKET, user, object_name)

    return JsonResponse({
        'data': '%s?AWSAccessKeyId=%s&Expires=%s&Signature=%s' % (url, AWS_ACCESS_KEY, expires, signature),
        'url': url,
})
```

My javascript:

```
function getSignedRequest(file){
  var token = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "/dashboard/sign_s3/?file_name="+file.name+"&file_type="+file.type);
  // xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
      if(xhr.status === 200){
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        uploadFile(file, response.data, response.url);
      }
      else{
        alert("Could not get signed URL.");
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}
function uploadFile(file, s3Data, url){
  var awskey = getParameterByName('AWSAccessKeyId', s3Data);
  var expires = getParameterByName('Expires', s3Data);
  var signature = getParameterByName('Signature', s3Data);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var token = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
  xhr.open("POST", s3Data);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
  var postData = new FormData();
  postData.append('AWSAccessKeyId', awskey);
  postData.append('Expires', expires);
  postData.append('Signature', signature);
  postData.append('file', file);    
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
      if(xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 204){
         //do something
      }
      else{
        alert("Could not upload file.");
      }
   }
  };
  xhr.send(postData);
}
```

Comment: What about boto?

Comment: @arcegk I've tried boto, as seen on the original Heroku doc, but I get the following error `fields['AWSAccessKeyId'] = self.credentials.access_key
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'access_key'` So nothing is even generated. The code listed above returns a signed url, but an incorrect signature. That's what I'm trying to figure out.